# Strange UDP packet loss

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, recv

I try to read UDP data-gram sequentially. But got issue during second read operation. You can see in below snippest where i try to read first time and lost 12 byte of packet from UDP receive buffer.

```
Snippest Code:
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_UDP);

bytesInBuffer = 0;
if (-1 == ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &bytesInBuffer))
{
  printf("%s:%d, Fail to read bytes in buffer\n", __func__, __LINE__);
  //If failure on ioctl then continue with select and read functionality
  bytesInBuffer = 0;
}
printf("%s:%d, bytesInBuffer: %d\n", __func__, __LINE__, bytesInBuffer);

errno = 0;
/* Now recv as it will not block */
i32RetVal = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 40, MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL);
printf("%s:%d, i32RetVal: %d\n", __func__, __LINE__, i32RetVal);

if (0 > i32RetVal)
{
    printf("%s:%d, Recv failed with status: %d, Err: %d, SErr: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, status, errno, strerror(errno));
    status = -1;
    break;
}
else if (0 == i32RetVal)
{
    /* other side closed its send pipe */
    status = -1;
    printf("%s:%d, Recv failed as other side closed pipe\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    break;
}

bytesInBuffer = 0;
if (-1 == ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &bytesInBuffer))
{
    printf("%s:%d, Fail to read bytes in buffer\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    //If failure on ioctl then continue with select and read functionality
    bytesInBuffer = 0;
}
printf("%s:%d, bytesInBuffer: %d\n", __func__, __LINE__, bytesInBuffer);

Output:
Recv_from:304, bytesInBuffer: 52
Recv_from:309, i32RetVal: 40
Recv_from:332, bytesInBuffer: 0
```

Question:
Why 12 bytes from read buffer got discarded?

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. :) And one more question if i have header and body to transmit through UDP then i need to prefer to transmit both together or both separately/sequentially?

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the `UDP(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html) you will see this entry for `FIONBIO`:

> ... Returns the size of the ***next pending datagram*** in the integer in bytes, or 0 when no datagram is pending. ...

(Emphasis mine.)

So the `FIONBIO` doesn't give you the number of bytes in the buffer, but the size of the next packet. If no new packet has been received you get zero.

Comment: I'm afraid that _"simply doing another recvfrom call will give you the rest of the data"_ is incorrect. UDP does not work that way.

Comment: @Damon You're correct, I don't use UDP often enough it seems. :)

Answer (score 3):

What your code does is this:

- Query the size of the next datagram in the receive buffer, which is 52 bytes
- Read 40 bytes from the next datagram in the receive buffer **and discard the rest**
- Check whether `recvfrom` returned 0, <strike>which will never be the case since the socket is not set to non-blocking</strike> -- my bad, overlooked the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag
- Assume wrongly that a zero-length receive means "other end has closed the connection" -- that's for TCP. UDP has no connections or "pipes", there is nothing to close: A zero length means a "no payload" datagram which consists only of the header (that's perfectly legal!)
- Query the size of the next datagram in the receive buffer (which is zero, since there is none)

Notably, UDP works on a strict per-datagram basis. You cannot read half a datagram (well, you can... but... read on).

No matter what happens, you will always receive a complete datagram or nothing. Datagrams may be lost (and *will* be lost), but not bytes. You will **also** always read a complete datagram ("read" as in "consume").

Reading a datagram removes it from the send buffer. Reading half a datagram (or any part of it) removes it from the send buffer, *discarding the rest*.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192809/udp-restreaming-using-socket-resulting-in-null-packets

Answer (score 1):

The buffer holds the datagram, not just the payload data.